# Grafana Http Error Bad Gateway when doing the official tutorial

Tags: windows-10, grafana

I am trying to do the official tutorial for [Grafana](https://grafana.com/tutorials/grafana-fundamentals/?utm_source=grafana_gettingstarted#4) but after pressing Save& Test I got "Http Error Bad Gateway"

Also, in the previous step when I did from the terminal

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Starting tutorial-environment_promtail_1 ...
Starting tutorial-environment_loki_1     ...
Starting tutorial-environment_grafana_1    ... error
Starting tutorial-environment_promtail_1   ... done
Starting tutorial-environment_loki_1       ... done
Creating tutorial-environment_prometheus_1 ...
Starting tutorial-environment_db_1         ... done
Starting tutorial-environment_app_1        ... done
Creating tutorial-environment_prometheus_1 ... done

ERROR: for grafana  Cannot start service grafana: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.


$ docker-compose ps
              Name                             Command               State                Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tutorial-environment_app_1          /bin/sh -c /app http://db  ...   Up       0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp
tutorial-environment_db_1           /db                              Up       0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp
tutorial-environment_grafana_1      /run.sh                          Exit 0
tutorial-environment_loki_1         /usr/bin/loki -config.file ...   Up       0.0.0.0:3100->3100/tcp, 80/tcp
tutorial-environment_prometheus_1   /bin/prometheus --config.f ...   Up       0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp
tutorial-environment_promtail_1     /usr/bin/promtail -config. ...   Up
```

What am I doing wrong, and how to solve it. Not being able to run the basic tutorial is troubling

EDIT:

I found what was failing.
I had to stop the Grafana service before doing the docker-compose

Comment: acccording the error message, port 3000 is not available or already claimed by another process.

Comment: port 3000 is being used by Grafana and the problem is on port 9090 (http://prometheus:9090/)